# PFQuery - run query against value of nested pointer?

Tags: parse-platform, pfquery

Is it possible to write a query against a field in a pointer inside another object.

Model Object

```
@interface Request

@property (nonatomic, retain) User *to; // pointer
@property (nonatomic, retain) Offer *offer; // pointer

@end
```

Query

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:NSStringFromClass([Request class])];
[query whereKey:@"to" equalTo:[User currentUser]];
[query whereKey:@"offer.status" equalTo:@YES];
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible. Using dot notation is only possible with includeKey in queries.

You need to build a compound query: https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries-compound/iOS

Comment: that won't do it, that works if both queries already have predefined arguments. In this case the arguments in my second query would be dependent on the result of my first query. I might have to write a cloud function to do this.